# Better saving and deploying site as wsp or programmatically creating lists, content types etc. in event receiver?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, wsp

In Sharepoint 2010 it is possible to save a site as a wsp solution package.
In my latest project a site consists of several subsites, lists, content types, permission groups views and so on. Creating all these things programmatically in a feature receiver is much efford.

Are there any disadvantages of saving and deploying the whole site as a wsp? I.e. will the site be ghosted on the target farm, and could the masterpage be changed later?

Thanks!